# I have a dataframe of 19 columns and need to get the max correlated variables among the dataset

Tags: correlation, pearson-correlation

```
 
    plt.figure(figsize=(19,19))  `PLot graph`
    g=sns.heatmap(df.corr(), vmin=df.corr().values.min(),
    vmax=1, cmap="coolwarm", linewidths=0.1,
    annot=False, annot_kws={"fontsize":4},
    xticklabels=1, yticklabels=1)           `Correlation heatmap`
    g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), fontsize = 7)
    g.set_yticklabels(g.get_yticklabels(), rotation = 0, fontsize = 7)
    plt.show()
```

I tried to show to correlated heatmap for 19 attributes in data frame however i  need to get the max correlated 2 different columns in dataframe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.